# Fama Macbeth Factor Modelling Run Variable Directly

Tags: factor-models

Why must we find the beta of a variable first before running the cross sectional regression for a factor model. Why can’t we just directly run the cross section of market cap versus return say for each time point?

Comment: I’m guessing one gives your the factor premium for a 1 percent move in exposure to the factor (I.e) regressing using beta and regressing using the variable directly will give you the premium for a 1 percent increase in market cap in the example above, it’s hard therefore to invest in 1% more of market cap?

Comment: I often see FM regressions run on firm characteristics rather than factor loadings. The point is if you want to control for market beta, then you first have to estimate this.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, if I do it on a characteristic however does the regression coefficient still represent the factor premium?